# Meu arquivo .ini (TIniFile.Create) do meu programa esta oculto e não consigo editar fora da aplicação

Tags: delphi, pascal, embarcadero

Boa tarde. Tenho uma aplicação mais completa, mas até no exemplo não funciona.
Tenho um programa que grava e faz a leitura de uma mensagem teste dentro de um arquivo conexao.ini criado em "TIniFile.Create(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'conexao.ini');". O problema é que indo diretamente a pasta de criação do arquivo "/com.embarcadero.Project1/files/conexao.ini" o arquivo não está lá ou é impossível de abri-lo.

```
procedure TForm1.btn_gravarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    ini : TIniFile;
begin
    ini := TIniFile.Create(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'conexao.ini');
    ini.WriteString('conexao.ini', 'Mensagem', edt_msg.Text);

    ini.Free;

    edt_msg.Text := EmptyStr;

    ShowMessage('Mensagem Gravada com Sucesso!');
    ShowMessage(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'conexao.ini');
end;

procedure TForm1.btn_lerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    ini : TIniFile;
    msg : String;
begin
    ini := TIniFile.Create(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'conexao.ini');
    msg := ini.ReadString('conexao.ini', 'Mensagem', '');

    ini.Free;

    ShowMessage(msg);
end;
```

OBS: O caminho onde busco o arquivo eu sei que é ele através do `ShowMessage(ShowMessage(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'conexao.ini'););`

Pergunta: Ele está oculto? Se está seria possível edita-lo fora da aplicação? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Qual a plataforma? Parece Mobile.

Comment: Android 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

**Copiei exatamente o seu código e o resultado saiu como esperado.**

Porém recomendo você a testar essas duas functions **paramstr** e **ExtractFilePath**

**paramstr**(0) Irá retornar o caminho completo de onde está seu .exe

**ExtractFilePath** irá retornar o caminho até a raiz.

Exemplo: paramstr(0) = C:\Users\PC\Documents\conexao.ini

ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) = C:\Users\PC\Documents\

Com a junção dos pois irá funcionar perfeitamente também.

Veja o código com uma leve alteração:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) + PathDelim + 'conexao.ini');
  Try
    ini.WriteString('conexao.ini', 'Mensagem', edt_msg.Text);
    edt_msg.Text := EmptyStr;

    ShowMessage('Mensagem Gravada com Sucesso!');
    ShowMessage(ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) + PathDelim + 'conexao.ini');
  Finally
    ini.Free;
  End;
end;
```

Obs: *Se seu Delphi Suportar Var inline*

E tente verificar essas opções no seu windows

[image: Exemplo]